# How to work around asynchronous process creating files while GitLab CI's `git clean` runs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Typical sequence of events:

1. Job starts a background service.
2. Job fails for some reason.
3. New job starts.
4. New job fails because the command from the previous job is still creating files. This results in error messages such as

   > warning: failed to remove /some/path: Directory not empty

   from `git clean`.

Things which *do not* work:

- `before_script` runs after `git clean`, so I can't clean up the state there.
- `after_script` is not guaranteed to run the same CI runner, so I can't use that to clean up the state.

Things which would technically work:

- Putting a massive `|| {first cleanup command; second cleanup command; …}` after every single command is not maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GitLab project CI/CD settings there is an option to `git clone` rather than `git fetch` to get the latest code. Since that presumably will `rm` the troublesome directory in its entirety it should work. This would be very slow for a big project, but in this case the source tree is only a few MB.

It works, but I'll award anyone who solves this in a more elegant way.